# TreeSets and abstract classes?

Tags: java, treeset

Design an abstract class called “Vehicle” which has members:

String color, Double speed, String nickname

and an abstract method:

public abstract double getNumberOfWheels();

Design concrete classes “Sedan”, “Motorcycle”, and “Truck” as subclasses of “Vehicle” 
Create objects of Sedan, Motorcycle, and Truck, and output the following information* 
 The type of the vehicle
 The color of the vehicle
 The nickname of the vehicle

In the order of
 Speed
 Color
 Number of Wheels

For example, if you create:

(1) Sedan object: nickname “wind” color “white” speed 100

(2) Motorcycle object: nickname “flash” color “black” speed 120

(3) Truck object: nickname “grandma” color “yellow” speed 88

I am a little confused on how to code the contrite classes. How exactly do I execute the output of these classes?

Here is my complete vehicle class:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
   String color;
   double speed;
   String nickname;


public Vehicle(String color, double speed, String nickname)
{

}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public double getSpeed() {
return speed;
}
public void setSpeed(double speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

public String getNickname() {
return nickname;
}
public void setNickname(String nickname) {
this.nickname = nickname;
}

public abstract double getNumberOfWheels(); 

 }
```

Here's sedan:

```
public class Sedan extends Vehicle {

public Sedan(String color, double speed, String nickname) {
    super(color, speed, nickname);

}
```

Do I have to make another string for type? and How do I get it to return those outputs? I am a little confused on the outputs.

Comment: Could not get your question clearly. You can make object - `Vehicle ob1 = new Sedan("White", 100.00, "Wind")` and can get the values like - `ob1.getColor()`. Is it something what you need?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change your vehicle class to define correct constructor:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
   String color;
   double speed;
   String nickname;

  public Vehicle(String color, double speed, String nickname)
  {
      this.color = color;
      this.speed = speed;
      this.nickname = nickname;
  }
  .....
}
```

Now you can define a concrete class as:

```
public class Sedan extends Vehicle {
    private double numOfWheels = 4.0;

    public double getNumberOfWheels()
    {
        return numOfWheels;
    }

    public Sedan(String color, double speed, String nickname) {
        super(color, speed, nickname);
    }

    public Sedan(String color, double speed, String nickname, double numOfWheels) {
        this.numOfWheels = numOfWheels;
        super(color, speed, nickname);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        return buff.append("Nickname = ").append(nickname).append(" color = ").append(color)
               .append(" speed = ").append(speed).append(" Num of Wheels = ")
               .append(numOfWheels).toString();
    }
}
```

And now the code for testing:

```
public class TestVehicle { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Sedan vehicle1 = new Sedan("red", 120.0, "XUV");
        Sedan vehicle2 = new Sedan("white", 160.0, "Safari", 6.0);
        System.out.println(vehicle1); // This will call toString method of Sedan class.
        System.out.println(vehicle2); // This will call toString method of Sedan class.
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of properties you can get using methods of the base abstract class - they all available for each subclass. Also you need to implement

```
public double getNumberOfWheels()
{
    // TODO: implementation of subclass
}
```

method for each subclass that is extends Vehicle class.
Please see link below, I think it would be helpful:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Sedan class inherited all of Vehicle's methods that have already implemented(i.e none abstract methods in this case), except for getNumberOfWheels();.  Your Vehicle class expects you to write a getNumberOfWheels() method in your Sedan Class. Then you can make a Sedan object!

Here is an example of what you could do to receive output.

```
public Sedan(String color, double speed, String nickname) {
    super(color, speed, nickname);

public double getNumberOfWheels(){
     return 4;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  Sedan BMW = new Sedan("Black",34,"idk");
  System.out.println(BMW.getNumberOfWheels());
  System.out.println(BMW.getSpeed());
}
}
```

Comment: Ok i see it now. I was supposed to just inherit the strings from the main vehicle class. I guess I misunderstood "type" thinking this would be another string.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a abstract method, which means you needs to give its details in the child class.

```
public class Sedan extends Vehicle {
    double numOfWheels = 4.0;

    public double getNumberOfWheels()
    {
        return numOfWheels;
    }

    public Sedan(String color, double speed, String nickname) {
        super(color, speed, nickname);
    }
}
```

To use these objects, you need a main() to create and use these objects.

```
public class UseVehicle { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Sedan car1 = new Sedan("white", 100, "wind"); 

        System.out.printf("car1: (%s, %d, %s) \n", 
        car1.getColor(), car1.getSpeed(), car1.getNickname());
    } 
}
```